# Zoom sometimes only shows one color channel from webcam

Tags: webcam, zoom-meeting

My coworker Bob's webcam image in Zoom recently started showing just the green channel:

[image: screenshot of zoom meeting]

The issue is intermittent: Sometimes it shows Bob's image normally, sometimes it looks like this. It might change back and forth between the two states several times during a meeting.

To Bob, on his own screen, his image always looks normal. He had no idea what we were talking about until we sent him screenshots. So it doesn't seem to be an issue with the webcam itself or its physical connection.

If his image is green, it's green for everyone else on the call; and if it's normal it's normal for everyone.

He is running the latest version of Zoom on Windows 10 on an ordinary Dell laptop with an ordinary Logitech webcam.

Any idea what might be going on?? It's not a big problem, but I'm just really curious what could possibly explain this.

Comment: Try in Zoom Settings > Video > Advanced, to disable hardware acceleration for "Sending Video". Also, did Bob just update his video driver before this started?

Comment: You published a bounty, but you never answered the above comment.

Comment: "If his image is green, it's green for everyone else on the call; and if it's normal it's normal for everyone."... As per the previous paragraph, I guess that is except for Bob, right?

Comment: @harrymc - I had him try disabling hardware acceleration for sending video a few days ago, and that seems to have done the trick. (Since the problem was intermittent and he doesn't see it himself, it's a bit hard to be sure.) Anyway if you want to post that as an answer, I'll award the bounty.

Comment: Out of curiosity @harrymc, how did you know to suggest hardware acceleration? have you come across this before? Any idea what explains the issue?

Comment: I didn't know. It's just a standard thing to try if a program mishandles the GPU.

Comment: I saw some cases (onAndroid) when the incoming video was not green, but "blue" (actually, the Cr and Cb channels got reversed somehow). This happened on a device that *did not have HW acceleration*. The Android app does allow changing HW acceleration toggle.

Comment: Am I missing something? My Zoom (on macOS) only lets me choose whether to use hardware acceleration for ***receiving*** video.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to go into Zoom *Settings > Video > Advanced*,
and then to disable hardware acceleration for "Sending Video".

Quite a few programs have problems with hardware acceleration, not only Zoom.
This is perhaps some incompatibility of the video codec that they use
with the hardware GPU, possibly caused by them misidentifying the GPU.